# How to determine the Spec code of an Intel Processor?

Tags: cpu

I currently own an [Intel Core 2 Quad Q8300](http://ark.intel.com/products/39107/Intel-Core2-Quad-Processor-Q8300-%284M-Cache-2_50-GHz-1333-MHz-FSB%29). According to the Intel processor specification page, over at [ark.Intel.com](http://ark.intel.com), it claims that only certain versions of the processor include VT-x and are low halogen. How can I determine which one is mine, based on its Spec code? ([As seen here](http://ark.intel.com/products/39107/Intel-Core2-Quad-Processor-Q8300-%284M-Cache-2_50-GHz-1333-MHz-FSB%29))

Two are boxed, one is retired, and two are marked "tray".

Is there a way of determining this information without opening up my computer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your system is running linux, or if you boot off a Live CD, you could try:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

and read the *flags* listed - you are looking for the presence of the **vmx** flag - eg:

flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm syscall nx lm constant_tsc pni monitor ds_cpl **vmx** est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr lahf_lm

If running Windows, use the [Intel Processor Identification utility](http://www.intel.com/support/processors/tools/piu/sb/cs-015478.htm)

[image]

But do note that the utility may still say 'no' to Virtualization Technology if your processor supports it but it has been turned off in the BIOS.

---

**Footnote**: I have just learnt something extra - you can *sometimes* turn the cpuid strings in the output of cat /proc/cpuinfo into a spec code - for example:

```
~/> cat /proc/cpuinfo 
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 15
model           : 4
model name      : Intel(R) Pentium(R) 4 CPU 3.20GHz
stepping        : 1
cpu MHz         : 3200.000
[snip]
```

Take the *cpu family* **in two digit Hex**, *model* and *stepping* and string them together thus:

Family + Model + Stepping so we get 0F (15 hex) 4  1  = 0F41

Then go to [this Intel page](http://ark.intel.com/SSPECQDF.aspx) and look up the ID code and relate it to a spec code - but note that some IDs are used for multiple spec codes.

Answer (score 0):

[CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) should be able to provide you with the spec code. It should also be physically on the CPU but that will require removing and reattaching your heatsink / fan.

[image]

Comment: I have CPU-z, could you indicate where exactly the spec code is on it?

Comment: under instructions on the main cpu tab it will list VT-X if it is supported. As for the exact spec code actually looking at the CPU is the only method I can find atm.

Comment: There is no spec code in CPU-Z. -1, sorry